# How to change the duration of a Thread.sleep() already sleeping

Tags: java, multithreading

I am looking for information on changing a Threads sleep pattern mid-sleep. Basically here is my situation laid out...

```
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        //Update Stuff...
        try {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + interval;
            String dateFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a").format(new Date(time));
            Thread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //Handle Errors...
        }
    }
}
```

So what I am doing is on program startup, it will take the interval (currently 60000), however the GUI has options to be able to change the interval (e.g. 1 hour, 2 hours, 3, etc). I can update just fine from the GUI and change the interval variable.

However when I change it, the thread is still sleeping and will wait until its finished, and update on the next iteration. What is the best way to interrupt this currently sleeping thread (or wake it up?). Also, I am concerned about making it "safe" as it will be running on a production server.

Any direction/guidance is awesome.

Comment: interrupt from gui, catch interruption in thread, start sleeping with new value

Comment: Interrupting it seems the cleanest answer, to me. BTW your comment `//Handle Errors...` is wrong; an interruption is not an error.

Comment: Are you required to change the sleep duration or are you able to simply call another Thread.sleep(anotherInterval) after the original one?

Comment: I am changing the next sleep duration - but would like to wake it up and run the processes again. E.g. everytime it changes the interval the base function is run again, then sleeps for the new interval.

Comment: How about instead of calling `sleep`, use a timed wait for something that can be signaled. When you change the sleep time, signal the object it's waiting for to break it out of its sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a simple solution through `wait`/`notify`.

Something like this:

```
class DurationSleeper {

    private final Object monitor = new Object();
    private long durationMillis = 0;

    public DurationSleeper(long duration, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        setDuration(duration, timeUnit);
    }

    public void sleep() {
        long millisSlept = 0;

        while (true) {
            synchronized (monitor) {
                try {
                    long millisToSleep = durationMillis - millisSlept;
                    if (millisToSleep <= 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    long sleepStartedInNanos = System.nanoTime(); // Not using System.currentTimeMillis - it depends on OS time, and may be changed at any moment (e.g. by daylight saving time)
                    monitor.wait(millisToSleep);
                    millisSlept += TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - sleepStartedInNanos);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Execution interrupted.", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setDuration(long newDuration, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            this.durationMillis = timeUnit.toMillis(newDuration);
            monitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with interrupt(), more like split sleep, lets say 1 minute and check if it is the time to wake up or sleep again. Overhead is next to nothing in such scenario.